# SharePoint Hosted app and document

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, document-center

I am creating a SharePoint document center application in which I want to achieve the following:

- We will use the SharePoint screen and will show the list of documents
  over the SharePoint site.

I have a question regarding SharePoint accessibility. Here the points are:

1. I have a SharePoint server and a SharePoint Site hosted on some server.

I would like to know the SharePoint provider hosted app which will let me access the SharePoint documents according to their access rights.

*Looking forward for the responses
Thanks 
Pawan*